# Checkbox not converting when sending email from html, javascript and aspx

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, contact-form

I am trying to convert a checkbox into a string that can be emailed using my asp.net code.  The code below is rewriting the Jquery script into ASP.net which works fine.  However, as outlined below in the code, the convert to string function is converting textfields and checkboxes.  The form is not converting the checkboxes.  It always brings them in as No, even when checked.

Here is the HTML code relating to the checkboxes.

```
   <input name="" id="check1" type="checkbox"><label for="check1"></label>
   <input type="hidden" value="false" name="check1" />

   <input name="" id="check2" type="checkbox"><label for="check2"></label>                                          
   <input type="hidden" value="false" name="check2" />

   <input name="" id="check3" type="checkbox"><label for="check3"></label>
   <input type="hidden" value="false" name="check3" />
```

I am pretty sure it has something to do with the JQUERY and/or ASP.net code.

```
Case 4 Contact Form
Response.Write(sendMailSE(Convert.ToString(Request.Form("name")), Convert.ToString(Request.Form("field1")), Convert.ToString(Request.Form("field2")), Convert.ToString(Request.Form("field3")), Convert.ToString(Request.Form("field4")), Convert.ToString(Request.Form("checkbox1")), Convert.ToString(Request.Form("checkbox2")), Convert.ToString(Request.Form("checkbox3")), Convert.ToString(Request.Form("comments"))))

    Public Function sendMailSE(ByVal field1, ByVal field2, ByVal field3, ByVal field4, ByVal checkbox1, ByVal checkbox2, ByVal checkbox3, ByVal comments) As String
    Try
        Const ToAddress As String = "jdoe@abcd.com"

        '(1) Create the MailMessage instance
        Dim mm As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("jdoe@abcd.com", ToAddress)

        'create cocantenated string for body of message
        Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()


        '(2) Assign the MailMessage's properties
        mm.Subject = "Contact Us: "
        sb.Append("Contact Us: " + vbCrLf)
        sb.Append("----------------------------------" + vbCrLf)
        sb.Append("Date " + DateTime.Now() + vbCrLf)
        sb.Append("Field1: " + field1 + vbCrLf)
        sb.Append("Field2:" + field2 + vbCrLf)
        sb.Append("Field3: " + field3 + vbCrLf)
        sb.Append("Field4: " + field4 + vbCrLf)
        sb.Append("Checkbox1 " + IIf(checkbox1, "Yes", "No") + vbCrLf)
        sb.Append("Checkbox2 " + IIf(checkbox2, "Yes", "No") + vbCrLf)
        sb.Append("Checkbox3 " + IIf(checkbox3, "Yes", "No") + vbCrLf)
        sb.Append("Comments: " + comments + vbCrLf)
```

I have removed the code below this line as it is immaterial.

Here is my JQUERY code pertaining to the posting of the function:

```
function sendmailse() {
                    $.post('formsend.aspx', { ch: 4, field1: $("#f1").val(), field2: $("#f2").val(), field3: $("#f3").val(), field4: $("#f4").val(), checkbox1: $("#txt_check1").val(), checkbox2: $("#txt_check2").val(), checkbox3: $("#txt_check3").val(), comments: $("#comments").val() }, function (data) {                       
                        $("#f1").val("");
                        $("#f2").val("");
                        $("#f3").val("");
                        $("#f4").val("");
                        $("#txt_check1").val("");
                        $("#txt_check2").val("");
                        $("#txt_check3").val("");
                        $("#comments").val("") 
                       });
              }
```

Here is the additional checkbox Jquery code suggested that i implemented:

```
function checkboxse()
            {
                 $('#check1').change(function checkboxse(){
                      if($(this).is(":checked"))
                         {
                             $('#txt_check1').val("true");
                         }
                      else
                         {
                             $('#txt_check1').val("false");
                         }
                 });

                 $('#check2').change(function checkboxse(){
                      if($(this).is(":checked"))
                         {
                             $('#txt_check2').val("true");
                         }
                      else
                         {
                             $('#txt_check2').val("false");
                         }
                 });

                 $('#check3').change(function checkboxse(){
                      if($(this).is(":checked"))
                         {
                             $('txt_check3').val("true");
                         }
                      else
                         {
                             $('txt_check3').val("false");
                         }
                 });
```

It is not working still.  As I said before, the checkbox is coming in as No everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of a checkbox to know whether it is checked or not simply doing like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/7yLx8o81/

`document.getElementById('check3').checked`

EDIT:
in order to adapt your code, you might want to remove the code of `function checkboxes` and inside the function `sendmailse`:

```
function sendmailse() {
    $.post('formsend.aspx', { 
        ch: 4,
        field1: $("#f1").val(),
        field2: $("#f2").val(),
        field3: $("#f3").val(),
        field4: $("#f4").val(),
        checkbox1: "\"" + document.getElementById('check1').checked + "\"",
        checkbox2: "\"" + document.getElementById('check2').checked + "\"",
        checkbox3: "\"" + document.getElementById('check3').checked + "\"",
        comments: $("#comments").val() 
    }, 
    function (data) {                       
           $("#f1").val("");
           $("#f2").val("");
           $("#f3").val("");
           $("#f4").val("");
           // remove because unused
           /* $("#txt_check1").val("");
           $("#txt_check2").val("");
           $("#txt_check3").val(""); */
           $("#comments").val("") 
       });
}
```

Comment: that isn't working, my form doesn't even submit now.  Are you sure we are supposed to delete the three checkbox lines in the function (data) section?

Comment: Have you tried to debug ? Does the console show some errors? There might be a typo somewhere... 
Since the `txt_check` are not used anymore, because there is no call to `checkboxes` removing/commenting the 3 lines in the success handler is safe.

Comment: seee my answer i just posted with the revised code.  Still no good.  It submitted fine before the changes but was saying No every time.